# Redux: Flatten nested data structure

Tags: typescript, redux, ngrx

I'm having a hard time rewriting a nested data structure to make use of redux state container (I'm using `ngrx` for Angular 2).

1. My data consists of many products

`(id, title, description, etc.).`

2. Every product has 1 or more "packages"

`(think: Cars have Premium, Exclusive, Sports etc. packages)`

3. Every package may have addons and/or configuration

`(addons as in Car + Premium + alloy wheels)`

`(configuration as in sports package with sport suspension)`

4. some config-options may have suboptions

Right now what I have is one deeply nested `Product` structure, which I would like to flatten out, because changing any deeper options is hell without mutating the state.

```
export class Product {
    public id: string;
    public title: string;
    public packages: ProductPackage[] = [];
}

export class ProductPackage {
    public id: string;
    public title: string;
    public sku: string;
    public config?: ProductPackageOptionGroup[];
    public addons?: ProductPackageOptionGroup[];
}

export class ProductPackageOptionGroup {
    public title: string;
    public options: ProductPackageOption[] = [];
    // Checkbox or radio
    public selectionmode: 'single' | 'multiple' = 'single';
}

export class ProductPackageOption {
    public title: string;
    public sku?: string;
    public key?: string;
    public value?: string;
    public options?: ProductPackageOption[] = [];
    public selectionmode: 'single' | 'multiple' = 'single';
}
```

- In the UI, the user first selects a product, than a package, and then selects addons and/or configures config-options.
- Switching between products should not reset the underlying package configurations.
- Only the corresponding packages should be displayed when a product is selected.

**How to flatten this structure to meet the requirements and have an easier time developing with redux?**

Comment: Maybe you should consider to give a try to Immutable.JS ?

Comment: Plus, I don't see any question here ... Can you clarify.

Comment: Added requirements and question

Comment: Why don't you use Immutable.JS ? It would help you manipulate those nested structures and also to make sure nothing is mutated in your reducers !

Comment: Its another library/API I dont want to learn/have the time to learn right now.

Answer (score 0):

The suggested approach to managing nested/relational data in Redux is to store it in normalized fashion, like a database.  Please see my answer at [Dealing with data consistency in a very large store in React + Redux SPA SaaS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40898017/dealing-with-data-consistency-in-a-very-large-store-in-react-redux-spa-saas/40898120#40898120) for links to more information.